# Showing a repeater in a popup div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

l would like to show the following  repeater in a popup div . the repeater being  bind to a  data table at the back end (Vb.net code)

l would like to show it as part of the data-content on hover for the following image

```
<div class="widget-canvas"> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="Rptjobs" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
         <table id="tblClients2" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="260px">
       <tr>
       <td>JOBDESCRIPTION</td>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        </tr>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr >
      <td valign="top"  >
       <a href="" class ="dashtext"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JOBDESCRIPTION")%>  </a>
    </td>
   <td valign="top" >
   <a style="padding-left:10px;" href="" class ="dashtext"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TOTAL")%></a> 
    </tr>
     <br />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
           <tr >
                 <td valign="top">
                     <a href=""  class ="dashtext"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JOBDESCRIPTION")%></a>
                 </td>
                 <td valign="top" >  
                     <a style="padding-left :10px;" href="" class ="dashtext"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TOTAL")%></a>
           </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
         FooterTemplate>
           </table>
         </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

```
<td><img src="Images/preview.png" style="width:18px; height:18px;" class="popTertiary" rel="popover" data-original-title=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CURRENTSTATUS")%> data-content=""></td>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, .net is irrelevant here as you are dealing with the generated HTML. It would be more useful to see that. Googling "javascript modal" would probably answer your question.

Comment: Which plugin using for popup?

Comment: bootstrap css and javascript bootstrap.js